# No name matching localhost found

Tags: spring-boot-admin

there
When using spring boot admin to monitor my local ssl app. it always show me the error "No name matching localhost found".
I enabled ssl communication both of my local ssl app(as admin client) and admin server app.
and admin client was successfully registered at the admin server.but once the client registered at the server. it always show the error "General SSLEngine problem" "No name matching localhost found".
I am sure that I added the client certificate as truststore to the server and added server certificate as truststore to the client. so I don't know why that error happened, can you guys give some advice? Thanks

Comment: the spingboot admin version is 2.1.6. F.Y.I

Answer (score 0):

Both sides(server, client)' public certifications need to be imported to each other.
Note: the public certification of client needs to be imported to JDK cacerts as well.